# Resolve full path for items returned from EWS based on Id and ParentFolderId

Tags: powershell, recursion, exchangewebservices

I've gotten myself into a bit of a hazzle.

I'm attempting to fetch the entire contents of an Exchange 2010 mailbox via Powershell and the Exchange Webservices API.

It's going alright to the point where I actually have the folders and the mail items.

I need to be able to add the full folder path of each individual mail item, so that when I export the whole thing to either xml og csv, I can group the emails by their folder's path.

I'm able to retrieve the folders and emails just fine.

Here's the way I fetch my mail items from a certain folder:

```
$ExchangeFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ExchangeService, [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::$FolderName)
[array] $ExchangeItems = $ExchangeFolder.FindItems($ItemLimit)

$PropertySet = New-Object
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
$PropertySet.RequestedBodyType = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType]::$BodyType

foreach ($ExchangeItem in $ExchangeItems)
{
    $ExchangeItem.Load($PropertySet)
    Write-Output $ExchangeItem 
}
```

And the way I fetch folders:

```
$RootFolderId = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderId([Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::Inbox,$MailboxName)
$RootFolder = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder]::Bind($ExchangeService,$RootFolderId) 
$FolderView = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(10000); 
$FolderView.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
$FolderView.PropertySet = $Propset 
$FolderResponse = $RootFolder.FindFolders($FolderView);
```

Mails are mapped to their folder via the `ParentFolderId` and folders have their own `Id` as well as a `ParentFolderId`.

From this information, I mean to somehow be able to grab hold of a random folder, and via the `ParentFolderId` be able to tell it's full path. I guess, it has something to do with making a recursive function but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I think that my plan for now is to:

1. Instead of a `Deep` folder traversal I'll use `Shallow` which only give me the folders which are children of the folder I'm currenly binded to.
2. Iterate through the folders and create a hash map consisting of the folder's `Id` as key and their `DisplayName` as value. Add a new Property to the folder object. Something like `\\<foldername>`.
3. Those of the folders who have any children, will be fetched, one level at a time, I'll look up their `ParentFolderId`in the hash map and will use the fetched value to update and append it with their own `DisplayName` to get their absolute location - e.g. `\\Inbox` from the parent and append it with their own `DisplayName` which could be something `Economy` resulting in a `\\Inbox\Economy` path which I, just as in (1) will add to the object.
4. Repeat this process, until all folders have been processed and mapped. With the `ParentFolderId` from the mails, I should now be able to tell their absolute location. I think...

Sorry if the above is a complete mess, I'm not quite up to speed with the recursive functions nor the EWS.

Any help will be much appreciated and if you need me to clarify any details, just ask.

Thanks in advance
Christian

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and used a recursive function to figure out the full path to an email item. (Im new to this also. It might not be the best way but it worked)

1. Get all the folders to store the 'ID' and 'ParentFolderId' property.

```bsh
    $view = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FolderView(999)
    $view.PropertySet = New-Object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.BasePropertySet]::FirstClassProperties)
    $view.PropertySet.Add([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderSchema]::DisplayName)
    $view.Traversal = [Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.FolderTraversal]::Deep
    $findFolderResults = $service.FindFolders([Microsoft.Exchange.Webservices.Data.WellKnownFolderName]::MsgFolderRoot, $view)
```

2. Pass the found folder properties to a recursive function, along with the parent folder id of the email item you wish to locate.

```bsh
    function jjRecursion{
      param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
      $results,
      [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)]
      $Id
      )
    $fullPath = @()
    $results | % {
        if ($_.id.UniqueId -eq $Id) {
            $fullPath += $($_.displayname)
            jjRecursion $results $_.ParentFolderId.UniqueId
        }
        else {}
    }
    RETURN $fullPath
    }
    
    $findPath = jjRecursion $findFolderResults $Item.ParentFolderId.UniqueId
```